# Can I get a class's name as a compile-time constant without hardcoding it in a string literal?

Tags: java, reflection, constants, compile-time-constant

I am working on an annotation processor.  This code compiles:

```
package sand;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("sand.Foo")
public class FooProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        return false; // TODO
    }
}
```

However, I am displeased by the string constant "sand.Foo" (not too much in this case, but more in general for the future).

If `Foo` is renamed or moved to another package, this code will still compile, but it won't work.

I would like to do something like:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(Foo.class)
```

That way, if Foo's name changes, the compilation will fail and someone will have to correct the file.

But this does not work because a `Class` is not a `String`.  So I tried:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(Foo.class.getName())
```

But the compiler does not consider this a constant expression, which is required in this context, so that won't work either.

Is there any way to coerce a class literal into its name at compile time?

Comment: What's the reason that you can't use a `Class` parameter instead of a `String`?

Comment: @chrylis SupportedAnnotationTypes only takes a `String...` as an input.

Comment: Sorry, I managed to miss that this was the one from the APT namespace. I suppose you could define your own annotation that takes a `Class` and use a processor to generate the code above?

Comment: `Is there any way to coerce a class literal into its name at compile time?` - nope, sorry, but see kapep's answer for a good alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the annotation, your processor can implement [`getSupportedAnnotationTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#getSupportedAnnotationTypes%28%29) to provide supported annotation type names at runtime:

```
Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
    Set<String> supportedAnnotationTypes = new HashSet<>();
    supportedAnnotationTypes.add(Foo.class.getName());
    return supportedAnnotationTypes;
}
```

---

In case you'd like to keep using (non-standard) annotations for this, you could create your own annotation that takes a compile time type as argument, like @k_g suggested. [@SupportedAnnotationTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/SupportedAnnotationTypes.html) isn't really anything special, it is only used automatically when you are extending `AbstractProcessor` anyway. Take a look at the [source code of `AbstractProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.java#AbstractProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes%28%29).

The signature of your custom annotation should use `Class<?>[]` instead of `String[]`:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SupportedAnnotationTypes {
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

Override `getSupportedAnnotationTypes` and look up your custom annotation in the same way as `AbstractProcessor`. For example like this:

```
public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
    Class<?>[] types = getClass().getAnnotation(SupportedAnnotationTypes.class).value();
    return Arrays.stream(types).map(Class::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own.

```
public @interface SupportedAnnotationTypes_Class {
    Class supported();
}
```

and then use `@SupportedAnnotationTypes_Class(supported = sand.Foo.class)` to use it.